# Select a div inside of multiple-responsive class div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-selectors

I have a simple page and I use Bootstrap to built it. I can't select `divs` that are inside of (responsive) multiple div classes.

My code example:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="well">
        <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/r6dxyfjbpOw4CG2feUhlUOLynUs.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive center-block img-thumbnail" alt="Michael Fassbender">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="well">
        <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/r6dxyfjbpOw4CG2feUhlUOLynUs.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive center-block img-thumbnail" alt="Michael Fassbender">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="well">
        <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/r6dxyfjbpOw4CG2feUhlUOLynUs.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive center-block img-thumbnail" alt="Michael Fassbender">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="well">
        <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/r6dxyfjbpOw4CG2feUhlUOLynUs.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive center-block img-thumbnail" alt="Michael Fassbender">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to style `well` classes for height. For example, for `col-lg-4`, I want to make the height of `well` class 600px. For `md` 500px, `sm` 400 and `xs` 350px, etc.

Comment: Share your CSS code

Comment: Why do your outer divs have all `col-xx` classes assigned at ones?

Comment: @all thats example: https://jsfiddle.net/utso57b8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to achieve different height by different breakpoint. It means, that you have to style your divs using media queries (each Bootstrap `col` class respond to a specific media query).

Your code should look similar to this:

```
.well { height: 350px; }

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
.well { height: 400px; }
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
.well { height: 500px; }
}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
.well { height: 600px;}
}
```

When simple `.well` doesn't select your div right, then you should use DevTools in your browser and check exact class of your div.

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your question, and without providing you `CSS`. 
Here's an example how I style the `col-lg-4 class` and the IMG within the `well class`

```css
body{
  background-color: black;
}
.col-lg-4{
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: maroon;
}
.col-lg-4 .well img{
  border-radius: 50px;
  width:150px; 
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: 23px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="well">
        <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/r6dxyfjbpOw4CG2feUhlUOLynUs.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive center-block img-thumbnail" alt="Michael Fassbender">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="well">
        <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/r6dxyfjbpOw4CG2feUhlUOLynUs.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive center-block img-thumbnail" alt="Michael Fassbender">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="well">
        <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/r6dxyfjbpOw4CG2feUhlUOLynUs.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive center-block img-thumbnail" alt="Michael Fassbender">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="well">
        <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/r6dxyfjbpOw4CG2feUhlUOLynUs.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive center-block img-thumbnail" alt="Michael Fassbender">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not work for my case. You can take a look to that [page](https://www.kafaizni.org/test/kisi.php?id=17288) to understand what I am talking about.